# Speed up autocomplete suggestions

Tags: json, jquery, autocomplete

I have a script which uses ajax(json) to fetch Google suggestions(xml), demo: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xbpk7/8/)

I think it reacts to slow, especially on the first keyup. So I want to speed it up. I first thought of doing the request on keydown instead of the default keyup. But that didn't speed it up and caused another problem; it was not possible to come down in the list anymore. So my question is: Is there any way of speeding up the first keyup(suggestions), and maybe the whole thing all together?

Comment: This operation will always be limited by the speed of your connection. The time is taken retrieving the data, not parsing the response or sending the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should speed up your Server side search engine first.
+ You could do auto complete just after user typed more than 3 or 4 letters. (Then it will pass less search result)
+ You could give some limits for your search query in server side
+ Also assign right indexes for the tables.

Also you could use Cache for search result.

Comment: I think these are all valid, im going for the cache I think. Thanks