# How to make autocomplete faster and smoother in React/Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, autocomplete

I've implemented a search bar with autocomplete.

The input component has an onChange property that triggers off an action creator that makes a GET request to my DB to fetch autocomplete suggestions.

I'm then returning and rendering the entire action.payload each time.

**onInputChange**:

```
onInputChange(event) {
    this.setState({ term: event.target.value });

    if (event.target.value.length >= 3) {
      setTimeout(this.props.fetchSuggestions(event.target.value), 1000);
    }
  }
```

**fetchSuggestions** (action creator):

```
export const fetchSuggestions = (term) => async dispatch => {
  const res = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/api/symptoms?query=${term}`);

  dispatch({
    type: constants.FETCH_SUGGESTIONS,
    payload: res.data
  });

}
```

**symptomSuggestions**(reducer):

```
export default function(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_SUGGESTIONS:
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

At the moment I've limited queries to length 3 or more and querying every 1s to limit the API calls I make to the database.

Given this implementation, are there any other ways I can improve the autocomplete feature to make it less laggy?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Speed up autocomplete suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496013/speed-up-autocomplete-suggestions)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add some debounce. Something like:

```
let lastFetched = 0;

onInputChange(event) {
  this.setState({ term: event.target.value });

  if (event.target.value.length >= 3 && (new Date() - new Date(lastFetched )) > 300) {
    lastFetched = Date.now();
    this.props.fetchSuggestions(event.target.value);
  }
}
```

This way you woun't be sending request every time that user types every single character, but only after slight period, after he finished typing.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe overkill but RxJS (aka redux-observable) has debounce built-in plus many other operators that can do throttling.